# How to make jar out of github sources?

Tags: java, collections, github, jar, mahout

There is a mahout-math project [on github](https://github.com/apache/mahout/tree/trunk/math/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/math). How can I make a jar out of it? I need to use the most recent code because the only one I could find [located here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-math/0.7/), is buggy. Errors I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project mahout-math: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
[ERROR] Command was/bin/sh -c cd "/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math" && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.19/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1800m -jar '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefirebooter7889542912600658589.jar' '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefire4878741926827070947tmp' '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefire_07139687171292447939tmp'
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project mahout-math: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
Command was/bin/sh -c cd "/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math" && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.19/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1800m -jar '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefirebooter7889542912600658589.jar' '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefire4878741926827070947tmp' '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefire_07139687171292447939tmp'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:322)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
Command was/bin/sh -c cd "/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math" && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.19/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1800m -jar '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefirebooter7889542912600658589.jar' '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefire4878741926827070947tmp' '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefire_07139687171292447939tmp'
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
Command was/bin/sh -c cd "/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math" && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.19/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1800m -jar '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefirebooter7889542912600658589.jar' '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefire4878741926827070947tmp' '/home/sophie/Documents/Code/libs/mahout/git/mahout/math/target/surefire/surefire_07139687171292447939tmp'
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:485)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:809)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:703)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:631)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
mkdir somedirectory
cd somedirectory
git clone https://github.com/apache/mahout.git
cd mahout/
cd math/
mvn clean package
ls target/mahout-math-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

You will need git and maven (mvn) installed on whatever os you are using.

Comment: I tried it, but it gives lots of errors and so can not compile. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

`git clone git://github.com/apache/mahout.git && cd mahout && mvn clean package` assuming you have git and maven. This will give you a jar in the `target` subfolder.